# xUnit mock method with lambda expression as input parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, mocking, xunit

I have a method like this one:

```
public Task<IEnumerable<VwSubscriptionProductsPf>> GetVwSubscriptionProductsBy(
    Expression<Func<VwSubscriptionProductsPf, object>> lambda)
{
    var result = GetList(lambda);
    return result;
}
```

The method is called like this:

```
var products = await _uow.VwSubscriptionProductsRepository
                   .GetVwSubscriptionProductsBy(s => s.SubscriptionId == subscription.Id);
```

And now I want to mock the return of the method using xUnit.

```
var products = new List<VwSubscriptionProductsPf> 
    { new VwSubscriptionProductsPf { SubscriptionId = 1, Name = "Product 1" }};

_uow.Setup(x => x.VwSubscriptionProductsRepository
    .GetVwSubscriptionProductsBy(s => s.SubscriptionId == 1))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(products.AsEnumerable()));
```

Can you tell me what am I missing?

PS. The problem is that the `GetVwSubscriptionProductsBy` returns an empty `IEnumerable`, and I'm waiting for the `IEnumerable` with one element manually created by me.

Comment: What is the `GetList` method?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski it is a method implemented by me, I don't think it should influence the result as I'm mocking GetVwSubscriptionProductsBy method

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay the problem is that the mocked object does not contain my return object, in returns an IEnumerable with 0 elements

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gXrUjh)

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, i discovered the problem, but I still can't fix it. The place where I call  ```_uow.VwSubscriptionProductsRepository.GetVwSubscriptionProductsBy``` method is called like this: ```var products = await _uow.VwSubscriptionProductsRepository.GetVwSubscriptionProductsBy(s => s.SubscriptionId == subscription.Id);``` and when I use ```subscription.Id``` as parameter for filtering it returns me empty IEnumerable. If I change ```subscription.Id``` with value ```1``` it works and returns me the IEnumerable with 1 product. How should I handle this case?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, the method can be mocked like this:

```
_uow.Setup(x => x.VwSubscriptionProductsRepository.GetVwSubscriptionProductsBy(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<VwSubscriptionProductsPf, object>>>()))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(products.AsEnumerable()));
```